# function to convert a number from a list in Python to output

Tags: python, function

I'm fairly new to python. I'm having a difficult time understanding how to use lists with functions.

My program asks for a number of participants and returns information for the number of participants entered.

I need to convert seconds to minutes from a list using a function, but I can't seem to get this working correctly.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and help me understand? So far, I have only tried to convert swimTimes with no luck.  I can do it correctly without the function.

```
## This function returns a list of participant last names
# :return: array of last names
def getLastNames():
    return [  # holds the last name of the participants
    'Adrian', 'Adserballe', 'Anderson', 'Anderson', 'Anderson',  'Andie', 'Andrews', 'Ardern', 'Arling', 'Arychuk']


## This function returns a list of participant first names
# :return: array of first names
def getFirstNames():
    return [  # holds the last name of the participants
'Jeff', 'Jacob', 'Julie', 'Jason', 'Micheal', 'Johan', 'Rhonnie','Clover', 'Curtis', 'Darlene']

## This function returns a list of the event the participant was in
# :return: array of events
def getEvent():
    return [  # holds the event id. 1 = standard tri, 2 = sprint tri
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]

## This function returns a list of the participant gender
# :return: array of gender
def getGender():
    return [  # holds the gender of the participant
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]

## This function returns a list of participant divisions
# :return: array of divisions
def getDivisions():
    return [  # holds the age group assignment for standard and sprint
'M4044', 'M4549', 'F4044', 'M4044', 'M5054', 'M3539', 'F4549', 'F3034', 'M4549', 'F5559']

## This function returns a list of swim times
# :return: array of swim times
def getSwimTimes():
    return [  # holds the swim times in seconds
    2026, 1768, 1689, 1845, 2248, 2583, 2162, 1736, 1691, 2413]

## This function returns a list of transition 1 times
# :return: array of transition 1 times
def getT1Times():
    return [  # holds the transition I times in seconds
    329, 224, 131, 259, 271, 264, 205, 164, 127, 285
]

## This function returns a list of bike times
# :return: array of bike times
def getCycleTimes():
    return [  # holds the cycling times in seconds
    4625, 4221, 4214, 4588, 5440, 5443, 4384, 4710, 4122, 5567]

## This function returns a list of transition 2 times
# :return: array of transition 2 times
def getT2Times():
    return [  # holds the transition II times in seconds
    35, 14, 21, 8, 45, 41, 2, 55, 1, 56]

## This function returns a list of run times
# :return: array of run times
def getRunTimes():
    return [  # holds the runTimes in seconds
    3847, 2882, 2864, 3106, 3835, 4139, 3158, 3477, 2856, 4190
    ]

## This function converts seconds to minutes
# :param: s is the seconds to convert
# :return: minutes in float format
def secToMin(s):
    s = int
    # Turns seconds into minutes
    min = s / 60 
    # returns number in minutes
    return min

## Main entry point of program
def main():
    #   declare parallel arrays and populate with data
    lastName = getLastNames()           # holds the last names of the participants
    firstName = getFirstNames()         # holds the first names of the participants
    division = getDivisions()           # holds the age group assignment for standard and sprint
    swimTimes = getSwimTimes()          # holds the swim times in seconds
    transition1Times = getT1Times()     # holds the transition I times in seconds
    cycleTimes = getCycleTimes()        # holds the cycling times in seconds
    transition2Times = getT2Times()     # holds the transition II times in seconds
    runTimes = getRunTimes()            # holds the runTimes in seconds
    event = getEvent()                  # holds the event id. 1 = standard tri, 2 = sprint tri
    gender = getGender()                # holds the gender of the participant

    numToDisplay = 0                    # holds the number of participants to display
    ttl = 0                             # total time accumulator in loop
    i = 0                               # index for the while loop
    numOfParticipants = 10              # holds the max index number for the arrays
#   Sets Flag
done = False
#   Executes the loop until done = True
while done != True:
    #   Gets the number of participants and sets the value in numToDisplay
    numToDisplay = int(input("\nHow many participants do you wish to display? "))
    #   Executes a loop until i is equal to the numToDisplay
    while i != numToDisplay:
        #   Writes "Name: " and the first and last nmae of participant
        print("\nName: " + firstName[i] + " " + lastName[i])
        #   Writes "Division: " and" the division number
        print("Division: ", str(division[i]))
        #   Evaluates the number in event and assigns a type of division
        if event[i] == 1:
            #   If event number is 1 then Standard Triathlon is assigned to event[i]
            event[i] = "Standard Triathlon"
        else:
            #   If event number is not 1 then Sprint triathlon is assigned to event[i]
            event[i] = "Sprint Triathlon"
        #   Writes Event: " and the event[i]: "1.5km Swim, 40km Bike, 10km Run"
        print("Event: " + event[i] + ": 1.5km Swim, 40km Bike, 10km Run")
        #   Evaluates the number in gender and assigns the gender to gender[i]
        if gender[i] == 1:
            #   If gender is equal to 1 then Male is assigned to gender[i]
            gender[i] = "Male"
        else:
            #   If gender is not equal to 1 then Female is assigned to gender[i]
            gender[i] = "Male"
        #   Writes "Gender: " and the gender
        print("Gender: " + str(gender[i]))
        #   Calls secToMin and assigns the minutes to swimTimes[i]
        swimTimes[i] = secToMin(min) # I don't think this is right
        #   Writes "Swim: " and dispaly swimtimes as a float with 2 decimal places
        print("Swim: %3.2f" % swimTimes[i])
        #   Writes "Transition 1: " and transition1Times[i] and "minutes"
        print("Transition 1: " + str(transition1Times[i]) + " minutes")
        #   Writes "Bike: " and cycleTimes[i] and "minutes"
        print("Bike: " + str(cycleTimes[i]) + " minutes")
        #   Writes "Transition 2: " and transition2Times[i] and "minutes"
        print("Transition 2: " + str(transition2Times[i]) + " minutes")
        #   Writes "Run:" and runTimes[i]) and " minutes"
        print("Run: " + str(runTimes[i]) + " minutes")
        #   Calculates the total time and assigns it to ttl
        ttl = swimTimes[i] + transition1Times[i] + cycleTimes[i] + transition2Times[i] + runTimes[i]
        #   Writes "Total: " and ttl and "minutes"
        print("Total: %3.2f" % ttl + " minutes" )
        #   Adds 1 to the index
        i += 1
    #   Asks if you want to view more participants and assigns the value to more    
    more = input("\nDo you wish to view more participants(Y/N)? ")
    #   If more is equal to yes i is reset back to 0 and done is set equal to False
    if more == "Y" or more =="y":
        i = 0
        done = False
    else:
        #   If more is equal to no then done is set equal to True
        if more == "N" or more == "n":
            done = True

### call main to run program
main()
```

Comment: `s = int` what do you want this to do? is `s` a one element list? like `s=[60]`. If so, you want `s=s[0]` to take the 0th integer out of the list.

Comment: where is the declaration or assigning value of `min`? and what type of problem or error you get?

Comment: @jacoblaw  I'm trying to get the seconds from getSwimTimes() and pass it to secToMin so i can convert it into minutes and return that value to swimTimes so i can display it as output.  I'm just confused on how to do it correctly

Comment: @R.A.Munna You are right. I completely forgot to declare it.  I just haven't been able to wrap my head around how to pass variables correctly between functions and lists.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `s = int` does not work, for casting you have to use `s = int(s)`, and in that specific case your values are `int` already.
Secondly `min` is a reserved word in python so you should not use that as a variable either.

you can pass a single element from the list, as you would with any array in another language:

```
            swimTimes[i] = secToMin(swimTimes[i])
```

or you can pass/return the whole list like so:

```
def getSwimTimes():
    return [  # holds the swim times in seconds
    2026, 1768, 1689, 1845, 2248, 2583, 2162, 1736, 1691, 2413]


def secToMin(arr):
    minutes = []
    for time in arr:
        minutes.append(time / 60)
    return minutes

print secToMin(getSwimTimes()) #prints [33, 29, 28, 30, 37, 43, 36, 28, 28, 40]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew I was doing something wrong I just didn't know what.  I have been searching all night for answers.